# php; remove single variable value pair from querystring

Tags: php

I have a page that lists out items according to numerous parameters ie variables with values.

```
listitems.php?color=green&size=small&cat=pants&pagenum=1 etc.
```

To enable editing of the list, I have a parameter edit=1 which is appended to the above querystring to give:

```
listitems.php?color=green&size=small&cat=pants&pagenum=1&edit=1
```

So far so good.

WHen the user is done editing, I have a link that exits edit mode.  I want this link to specify the whole querystring--whatever it may be as this is subject to user choices--except remove the edit=1.

When I had only a few variables, I just listed them out manually in the link but now that there are more, I would like to be able programmatically to just remove the edit=1.

Should I do some sort of a search for edit=1 and then just replace it with nothing?

```
$qs = str_replace("&edit=1, "", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?{$qs}'>return</a>;
```

Or what would be the cleanest most error-free way to do this.

Note: I have a similar situation when going from page to page where I'd like to take out the pagenum and replace it with a different one.  There, since the pagenum varies, I cannot just search for pagenum=1 but would have to search for `pagenum =$pagenum` if that makes any difference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'd use [http_build_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php), which nicely accepts an array of parameters and formats it correctly. You'd be able to unset the edit parameter from `$_GET` and push the rest of it into this function.

Note that your code has a missing call to `htmlspecialchars()`. A URL can contain characters that are active in HTML. So when outputting it into a link: Escape!

Some example:

```
unset($_GET['edit']); // delete edit parameter;
$_GET['pagenum'] = 5; // change page number
$qs = http_build_query($_GET);

... output link here.
```

Comment: How would I do this from $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']?

Comment: There is `parse_url()` and `parse_str()`, but $_GET is always available and filled, so this is not necessary.

Comment: I wouldn't modify the $_GET variable (or any superglobals for that matter) because they could be needed elsewhere in the application. Instead, create a temporary variable like `$edit_query = $_GET;`. Then you can `unset($edit_query['edit']);` without affecting your superglobals.

Answer (score 9):

Here's my shot:

```
/**
*   Receives a URL string and a query string to remove. Returns URL without the query string
*/
function remove_url_query($url, $key) {
    $url = preg_replace('/(?:&|(\?))' . $key . '=[^&]*(?(1)&|)?/i', "$1", $url);
    $url = rtrim($url, '?');
    $url = rtrim($url, '&');
    return $url;
}
```

Returns:

```
remove_url_query('http://example.com?a', 'a') => http://example.com
remove_url_query('http://example.com?a=1', 'a') => http:/example.com
remove_url_query('http://example.com?a=1&b=2', 'a') => http://example.com?b=2
```

Kudos to David Walsh.

Answer (score 3):

## Another solution, to avoid  `&amp;`  problems too!!!

```
remove_query('http://example.com/?a=valueWith**&amp;**inside&b=value');
```

Code:

```
function remove_query($url, $which_argument=false){ 
    return preg_replace('/'. ($which_argument ? '(\&|)'.$which_argument.'(\=(.*?)((?=&(?!amp\;))|$)|(.*?)\b)' : '(\?.*)').'/i' , '', $url);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't work if `edit=1` is the first variable:

```
listitems.php?edit=1&color=green&...
```

You can use the `$_GET` variable to create the query string yourself. Something like:

```
$qs = '';
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value){
    if ($key  == 'pagenum'){
        // Replace page number
        $qs .= $key  . '=' . $new_page_num . '&';
    }elseif ($key  != 'edit'){
        // Keep all key/values, except 'edit'
        $qs .= $key  . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
    }
}
```