# Tracking API usage and GDPR Compliance

Tags: php, api, privacy

I have set up a very simple API which provides data in JSON format.

I want to track usage of the API so I can see if anyone is abusing the service by making a huge number of requests.

The only way I can think to do that, is to track the user's IP address and user agent, so I am doing this simple thing once I have confirmed their API key is valid:

```
$ua  = $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$ip  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// get querystring data but strip out the 'api_key' bit for recording usage in database
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122563/php-remove-single-variable-value-pair-from-querystring
$qs2 = NULL;
foreach ($_GET as $keyv => $value){
    if ($keyv  != 'api_key'){
        $qs2 .= $keyv  . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
    }
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO j_un_api_log (fld_date, fld_user_id, fld_ip, fld_ua, fld_qs) VALUES (now(), :user_id, :ip, :ua, :qs)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
$stmt->bindParam(':ip', $ip);
$stmt->bindParam(':ua', $ua);
$stmt->bindParam(':qs', $qs2);
$stmt->execute();
```

However, due to GDPR (https://eugdprcompliant.com/personal-data/) legislation, the view is that:

> all IP addresses should be treated as personal data, in order to be
>   GDPR compliant

I realise this is risking moving into being off-topic, however - I think this is programming related, because I am not sure how to proceed here.

If I have a Terms and Conditions section that states I will store the IP address and User Agent each time the API is called to track usage and prevent abuse, and ask users to accept the Terms and Conditions on registering, does that mean I can store the IP addresses and user agent data?

If I can't, as far as I can see there is no way to track usage other than simply storing maybe only the user-id, date and time and querystring for each call.

If I also cannot store the IP address and user agent for the user who registered, then presumably there is no way to, for example, block a troublesome user who is hammering the API.

I realise I could build in systems to prevent high volume use but this is a basic API and I wanted to start out by simply monitoring what's going on and take it from there.

Comment: You are not allowed to store an IP, but a number is ok to save. The way I do it is to remove the dots from the IP and do some math on the number. This gives me an almost unique number (duplicates can happen) that is in line with regulations. (As far as I know). Edit; now that I think about it. If you explode on dot and say multiply [0] with 2, and [1] with 5 and [2] with 3 and so on and just implode there array you will have an unique number that only you know how to recreate backwards to an IP. And even you will have a hard time doing it.

Answer (score 2):

GDPR does not say that you can’t use IP addresses, but that you have to have a reasonable basis for using them, tell people if you do, that you do not keep them for longer than necessary, and not to share them with third parties. Using them for protection against abuse is a perfectly reasonable basis, so long as that’s what you say, and what you do.

For rate limiting, most firewalls will do that with little overhead (purely on IP, not ID). The way to do it safely within your own app would be to index hits according to a hash of IP and ID. Since you can’t get from a hash back to the original data, it’s safe to retain without additional warnings.