# PHP Remove cid at the end of the url

Tags: php, substr, strpos

I am working on my PHP to fetch the cid images from the email body. I would like to remove the `cid:ii_jv1bt7pm0`, `cid:HeaderImage` or whatever it is that show at the end of the url.

When I try this:

```
$cid = 'cid:'.substr($cid, 1, strlen($cid)-2);
```

It will show the cid at the end of the url, for example:

> http://example.com/#inbox/u/?id=123456&attid=0.1&msgid=1630808059112201633&view=attachment&display=viewii_jv1bt7pm0

So I want to achieve to make it to show like this:

```
http://example.com/#inbox/u/?id=123456&attid=0.1&msgid=1630808059112201633&view=attachment&display=view
```

Here it is the output for `$cid`:

```
cid:ii_jv1bt7pm0
cid:HeaderImage
```

I want to remove the strings to replace it with the empty strings so these strings would not be show at the end of the url.

Here is the full code:

```
<?php

require_once "Mail.php";
require_once('Mail/IMAPv2.php');
$username = 'myusername';
$password = 'mypassword';
$mailserver = '{imap.example.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}'.$_POST['mailserver'];

$mailbox = imap_open($mailserver, $username, $password) or die("Can't connect: " . imap_last_error());
email_number = 'somerandomnumbers';
$attachment = getAttachment($mailbox, $email_number);

function getAttachment(&$mail, $email_number) {


    $attachments = $mail->attachments;
    $msgNo = trim($mail->headerInfo->Msgno);
    $key = "somekeys";
    $email_id = bin2hex(openssl_encrypt($email_number, 'AES-128-CBC', $key));
    $attach_id = 0;
    $inline_id = 0.1;
    $html = '';

    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        $partNo = $attachment['part'];
        $filename = $attachment['filename'];
        $filename = htmlentities($filename);

        $cid = $attachment['id'];

        if (isset($cid)) {

            if (strpos($mail->htmlText, 'viewHeaderImage')) {
                $mail->htmlText = str_replace('viewHeaderImage', 'view', $mail->htmlText);
            }
            else {
                $cid = 'cid:'.substr($cid, 1, strlen($cid)-2);
            }

            if($filename == 'noname.gif') {
                $tempfile = '/u/?id='.$email_id.'&attid='.$inline_id.'&msgid=1630808059112201633&view=attachment&display=view';
            }
            else {
                $tempfile = '/u/?id='.$email_id.'&attid='.$inline_id.'&msgid=1630808059112201633&view=attachment&display=view';
            }
            $mail->htmlText = EmailEmbeddedLinkReplace($mail->htmlText, $cid, $tempfile);
        }
    }
}


function EmailEmbeddedLinkReplace($html, $cid, $link)
{
    // In $html locate src="cid:$cid" and replace with $link.
    $cid = 'cid:'.substr($cid, 1, strlen($cid)-2);
    $newHtml = str_replace($cid, $link, $html);
    return $newHtml;
}
```

I have tried to use `$cid = '';` but it would not make any difference because the cid will still show at the end of the url.

Can you please show me an example how I could be able to remove the `cid:ii_jv1bt7pm0`, `cid:HeaderImage` or whatever it is to get it removed so they will not show at the end of the url?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php; remove single variable value pair from querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122563/php-remove-single-variable-value-pair-from-querystring)

Comment: Could you write a better example? not the code, example. I can't understand what you actually want.

Comment: @ehymel This is not the same as mine as mine is different. Please check my question again.

Comment: @LIGHT What example do you want me to expect? I have already post an example url of what it look like as the `ii_jv1bt7pm0`, `HeaderImage` at the end of the url next to view like `viewii_jv1bt7pm0`, `viewHeaderImage`. What I want to make it to show `view` at the end of the url without the  `viewii_jv1bt7pm0`, `viewHeaderImage`. Make sense?

Comment: in which variable does `ii_jv1bt7pm0` or `HeaderImage` finally exists?

Comment: Both of them will exist in the `$cid` variable once a time when I use `0.1`, `0.2`, `0.3 next to the attid in the url. They are showing random strings for the cid. How I can remove it?

Comment: is your display always going to be 'view' ? and do you have access to just cid somewhere else in your program ?

Comment: @PooyaEstakhri it will always display `viewii_jv1bt7pm0` and `viewHeaderImage`. No I dont have access cid somewhere in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment in `EmailEmbeddedLinkReplace()`, it seems like this is what you need:

```
function EmailEmbeddedLinkReplace($html, $cid, $link)
{
    // In $html locate src="cid:$cid" and replace with $link.
    return str_replace('src="cid:'.$cid.'"', $link, $html);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for this as I can see it is working great. Problem are now resolved.

Comment: @ François Huppé: Yes but it have been resolved. You have forgot to include the `src=.$link` in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that I didn't completely understand the nature of your question. However,

```
$cid = "http://example.com/#inbox/u/?id=123456&attid=0.1&msgid=1630808059112201633&view=attachment&display=viewii_jv1bt7pm0";
$cid = substr($cid,0,strrpos($cid,"display=view")+12);
echo $cid;
```

In this code, I have used `strrpos` to find the last `display=view` of the `$cid`, and then add the length of `display=view`, i.e. 12. Finally I trimmed the URL from `0-index` to the `end-index` of `display=view`.

The output for the code above will be:

> http://example.com/#inbox/u/?id=123456&attid=0.1&msgid=1630808059112201633&view=attachment&display=view

Hope this helps

Comment: I can see it is working now so how I could use them in the `EmailEmbeddedLinkReplace` function? can you please post an example how I could use it?

Comment: For that, I'll need sample value for `$html`, `$link` and `$cid`

Comment: OK, the value for $link is `/project/u/?id=425965486959666a6b6f7731624865745733357952513d3d&attid=1.1&msgid=1630808059112201633&view=attachment&display=view`, $cid `cid:ii_jv1bt7pm0` and $html `<img src="cid:ii_jv1bt7pm0" alt="what-is-bootstrap.png" width="452" height="302" class="gmail-CToWUd gmail-a6T" tabindex="0"><img src="cid:HeaderImage" class="CToWUd">`

Answer (score 0):

Use `rtrim` to remove the last str from a string.

```
echo rtrim("http://example.com/#inbox/u/?id=123456&attid=0.1&msgid=1630808059112201633&view=attachment&display=viewii_jv1bt7pm0","ii_jv1bt7pm0");
```