# Php parse url and remove parametr issue

Tags: php, url

I have url like this :

```
/leads/set_attributes.html?lead_id=3793&name=TEST
```

I need remove 'name' and return url.
I try do it like this:

```
$vars = [];

parse_str(html_entity_decode($sAddQuery), $vars);

unset($vars['name']);

$sAddQuery = http_build_query($vars);
```

But i always get

```
%3Flead_id=3793
```

as result. I tried use html_entity_decode for array elements but it did not help. How can i solve this? Thanks

Comment: What is in `$sAddQuery`? The entire `/leads/set_attributes.html?lead_id=3793&name=TEST` path or only the query string?

Comment: Either way, `html_entity_decode` is unnecessary here. Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122563/php-remove-single-variable-value-pair-from-querystring).

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code to :

```
 <?php
   $url = parse_url('/leads/set_attributes.html?lead_id=3793&name=TEST');
   $str = $url['query'];
   parse_str($str, $params);  //parse URL
   unset($params['name']);   //unset name parameter
   $string = http_build_query($params);   //again built the URL string
   var_dump($string);
 ?>
```

Hope it works!